# Is it possible to place an object on the floor by Altitude (or sea level) in ARKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, cllocation, altitude

recently I started to work with ARKit And place an object by tapping on map and follow the lead to reach to the Object. It's working perfectly but I have a problem: when I reach the object, it's not placed on floor and is up in the air
Is there any solution like combining location parameters with hitTest?
thank you for your time.